# TypeScriptでenumを使用して型を当てたい。

Tags: javascript, typescript

enumをリテラル型のような使い方は出来ないのでしょうか？

```
enum UserIds {
  'たけし' = 1,
  'かける' = 2,
  'みさと' = 3,
}

// 1, 2, 3以外の数値はエラーになってほしい
const userId: UserIds = 30;
console.log(userId);
```

リテラル型を `type UserIds = 1 | 2 | 3;` を使えばできるのは知っているのですが、すでに上記のようなenumが用意してあってこれを元に型を当てたいのですが何か良い方法をご存知の方いないでしょうか。
お願いいたします。

ドキュメント
[TypeScript - Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScriptのenumには**問題点**があります。まさにご質問のようなコードでエラーを起こしてくれないという点です。
現状、enum（const enumでも同様）をenumのまま使ってこの問題点を回避する方法はなさそうで、enumを使わない方がいいことについては複数の記事でも挙がっています。
[[Typescript] 「なぜ enum の利用が推奨されないのか？」をまとめてみた - Qiita](https://qiita.com/saba_can00/items/696baa5337eb10c37342)
[列挙型(enum)の問題点と代替手段 | TypeScript入門『サバイバルTypeScript』](https://typescriptbook.jp/reference/values-types-variables/enum/enum-problems-and-alternatives-to-enums)
 [さようなら、TypeScript enum - 株式会社カブク | 株式会社カブク](https://www.kabuku.co.jp/developers/good-bye-typescript-enum)

Comment: 余談なんですが、私もenumがどうしても使いたくて、過去に他所で質問をしたところ「const enumを使えばいいよ」と教えてもらいました。しかし、今ご質問のコードでconst enumを試してみたところ、問題点は解決されませんでした。

Comment: ありがとうございます。enumは使わない方が良さそうですね。